# How to rename all files in folders with pattern

Tags: regex, linux, bash, perl

I have a bunch of files like:

```
bla.super.lol.S01E03.omg.bbq.mp4
bla.super.lol.S01E04.omg.bbq.mp4
bla.super.lol.s03e12.omg.bbq.mp4
```

I need to rename them all like:

```
s01e03.mp4
s01e04.mp4
s03e12.mp4
```

I've tried to do it with `for file in *; do mv $file ${file%%\.omg*}; done` but it removes only part after S01E01, not before it
so please, help

Answer (score 4):

Many Linuxes ship a nice command line tool called `rename` that eats Perl regular expressions:

```
rename 's/.*\.(\w+\d)\..*/$1.mp4/;y/A-Z/a-z/' *.mp4
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple Perl script that tries to parse out the episode information, skips files where it can't find them.

```
#!perl 

use strict;
use warnings; 

use File::Copy qw(move);

foreach my $file ( glob('*.mp4') ) {
   my ($info) = $file =~ m/([sS]\d+[eE]\d+)/;
   next unless $info;

   my $new_filename = lc $info . ".mp4";    
   move $file, $new_filename
      or die "$!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**A pure Bash solution**:

```
for f in *.mp4; do
    IFS=. read -r _ _ _  s _ <<< "$f"
    mv -- "$f" "${s,,}.mp4"
done
```

To test it, I created the following tree:

```
tree
.
├── bla.super.lol.S01E03.omg.bbq.mp4
├── bla.super.lol.S01E04.omg.bbq.mp4
└── bla.super.lol.s03e12.omg.bbq.mp4

0 directories, 3 files
```

Let's put a `printf` before `mv` to be sure about the changes:

```
mv -- bla.super.lol.S01E03.omg.bbq.mp4 s01e03.mp4
mv -- bla.super.lol.S01E04.omg.bbq.mp4 s01e04.mp4
mv -- bla.super.lol.s03e12.omg.bbq.mp4 s03e12.mp4
```

Looks good. The season part is extracted, and lower-cased as requested.

Answer (score 0):

If your filenames are *always* dot-separated and the SExxEmm part is *always* the 4th one, then I'd do it with awk:

```
for file in *; do 
    mv $file $(echo $file | awk -F. '{print $4 "." $NF}');
done
```

`awk -F.` splits the filename at the dots apart and then prints the 4th and last field.

To do a "dry run" (i.e. show the commands instead of executing them), prepend them with `echo`:

```
for file in *; do 
    echo mv $file $(echo $file | awk -F. '{print $4 "." $NF}');
done
```